# Шифрование открытым ключом TLS

Tags: ssl, rsa, aes, tls, sha

Имеется *TLS handshake* с сертификатом, используя который необходимо шифровать трафик. В HEX последовательности находится *ServerHello, Certificate и ServerHelloDone*. Согласно договоренности клиента и сервера используется шифронабор **TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA** (128-битное шифрование AES с аутентификацией сообщений SHA-1 и обменом ключами RSA). Следом за посланным сервером сертификатом клиент должен отправить *ClientKeyExchange*. Цитата из стороннего ресурса:

> В случае использования RSA, клиент генерирует 48-байтовый случайный секрет (при этом первые два байта содержат версию используемого протокола), шифрует его открытым ключом сервера (этот ключ передаётся в составе серверного SSL-сертификата или в сообщении ServerKeyExchange) и передаёт зашифрованные данные на сервер.

*ServerKeyExchange* сервер не передает, соответственно открытый ключ сервера должен содержаться в сертификате. В моем случае длина данных сертификата 728 байт. Не получается найти алгоритм действий в результате выполнения которых получится из сертификата открытый ключ сервера и ClientKeyExchange. Прошу помочь в решении вопроса, желательно с примерами или ссылками, в качестве примера в случае необходимости используйте произвольные данные.

Comment: А почему не посмотреть исходный код какой-нибудь реализации?

Comment: Потому что так можно ответить на четверть вопросов которые вообще когда либо задавались на сайте, я прошу пережевать и проглотить вместо меня а не усложнить процесс изучения

Comment: так вы ленитесь или вам не понятно? на каком языке вы ожидаете пример?

Comment: Мне не понятно, мой уровень знаний в программировании ниже среднего и боюсь изучать код других людей для меня непомерный труд т.к. возникнут проблемы с поиском кусков кода с реализацией, впринципе язык любой, главное чтобы была затронута суть и желательно код пояснять